# Attempt to invoke "...CameraCaptureSession.abortCaptures()" on a null object

Tags: android, facebook, live-streaming, android-camera2, facebook-live-api

Trying to use Facebook Live api with my android app. I am using camera2 to pull up the camera on my live streaming activity but am getting this error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.abortCaptures()' on a null object reference
                                                                     at com.example.mapdemo.StreamingActivity$4.onClick(StreamingActivity.java:151)
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
                                                                     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11157)
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
```

I am not sure why this is an error. Here is the code around the line where the error is located...the line with the error begins with mCaptureCameraSession.abortCaptures():

```
package com.example.mapdemo;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v13.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StreamingActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback2 {

    private static final String TAG = "StreamingActivity";
    private static final String[] REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{
            android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA = 1;

    private CameraManager mCameraManager;
    private VideoEncoderCore mVideoEncoderCore;
    private String mFrontCameraId, streamURL,name,surname;
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    private SurfaceView mSurfacView;
    private Button buttonRecord;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private ArrayList<Surface> mSurfaces;
    private CaptureRequest mCaptureRequestPreview;
    private StreamModel streamModel;
    private CaptureRequest mCaptureRequestRecord;
    private CameraCaptureSession mCameraCaptureSession;
    private CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback mCaptureSessionCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
            mCameraCaptureSession = session;
            try {
                mCameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                        mCaptureRequestPreview,
                        new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {},
                        mBackgroundHandler
                );
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
            Log.d(TAG, "fafea") ;
        }
    };
    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraDeviceCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            mCameraDevice = camera;
//           mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession();
//
//            try {
//                mCameraManager.setTorchMode(mFrontCameraId, true);
//            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera,  int error) {
            //@IntDef(value = {CameraDevice.StateCallback.ERROR_CAMERA_IN_USE, CameraDevice.StateCallback.ERROR_MAX_CAMERAS_IN_USE, CameraDevice.StateCallback.ERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED, CameraDevice.StateCallback.ERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE, CameraDevice.StateCallback.ERROR_CAMERA_SERVICE})
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_streaming);


        mSurfacView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        mSurfacView.getHolder().addCallback(StreamingActivity.this);
        streamModel = new StreamModel();
/**
 LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(
 this,
 Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));*/

        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/live_videos", null, HttpMethod.POST,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        //Gson mGson = new Gson();
                        //streamModel=mGson.fromJson(response.toString(),StreamModel.class);
                        try {
                            streamURL=response.getJSONObject().get("stream_url").toString();
                            Log.e(TAG,response.getJSONObject().get("stream_url").toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();

        buttonRecord =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRecord);
        buttonRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isRecording){
                    try {
                        mCameraCaptureSession.abortCaptures();
                        mCameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                                mCaptureRequestPreview,
                                new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {},
                                mBackgroundHandler
                        );
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    isRecording = false;
                    buttonRecord.setText("Play");
                }
                else{
                    isRecording = true;
                    try {
                        mCameraCaptureSession.abortCaptures();
                        mCameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestRecord, new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                                mVideoEncoderCore.drainEncoder(false);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCaptureSequenceAborted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, int sequenceId) {
                                super.onCaptureSequenceAborted(session, sequenceId);
                                mVideoEncoderCore.drainEncoder(true);
                            }
                        }, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    buttonRecord.setText("Stop");
                }
            }
        });
        mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            String[] cameraIds = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList();
            if (cameraIds.length != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cameraIds.length; i++){
                    if (mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraIds[i]).get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)
                            == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT){
                        mFrontCameraId = cameraIds[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mVideoEncoderCore != null) {
            mVideoEncoderCore.release();
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    private void openCamera(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
            return;
        }
        try {
            mCameraManager.openCamera(mFrontCameraId, mCameraDeviceCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { // there were 2 different types pf activity compats to import
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        try {
            mCameraManager.openCamera(mFrontCameraId, mCameraDeviceCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceRedrawNeeded(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        startBackgroundThread();
        openCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
/**
 private String getVideoFilePath(Context context) {
 return Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + "/"
 + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
 }
 */
/**
 public void createCaptureSession(){
 try {
 mVideoEncoderCore = new VideoEncoderCore(
 1280,
 720,
 4000000,
 streamURL
 );
 Surface previewSurface = mSurfacView.getHolder().getSurface();
 Surface encoderSurface = mVideoEncoderCore.getInputSurface();
 CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
 captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
 mSurfaces = new ArrayList<>();
 mSurfaces.add(previewSurface);
 mSurfaces.add(encoderSurface);
 mCaptureRequestPreview = captureRequestBuilder.build();
 captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(encoderSurface);
 mCaptureRequestRecord = captureRequestBuilder.build();
 mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(mSurfaces, mCaptureSessionCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
 } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 */



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Camera2 API has many asynchronous tasks associated with it - tasks that run in the background to complete some work, like opening the camera, closing the camera, getting focus etc.

These task use callbacks to report when they are complete.

In addition to this the activity or fragment itself may invoke other tasks in the background, which also use callbacks to communicate and which may interact with the camera also - for example the camera will typically be closed during activity or fragment pause events.

Managing all the callbacks can be tricky and race conditions can exist - you will find other Camera2 race condition questions and answers on Stackoverflow also.

In your case, the error is telling you that the captureSession object is null. The most likely reason for this is because it has been set to null, either by an out of sequence Callback due to a race condition, or because you inadvertently set it to null as part of your clean up before you were fully finished with it.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. How do I go about finding the race condition and resolving it? @Mick

Comment: Unfortunately, it is tricky - using a debugger will change the timing and may hie the problem. I usually find a mixture of searching where the variable is used in the code, along with adding debug logs around its use works best.

Comment: Thanks @Mick I'm not sure if you can, but if you could glance at the the entire Streaming activity I posted above and see if anything jumps out at you that would be great.

Comment: You never actually create the captureSession in the code you included - the code to create it has been commented out - i.e. 'createCaptureSession'. Its the capture session object which is null, btw - answer updated to make this clear.